# document.getElementById is undefined in Vue2 component...because misusing watch?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am making a basic chat component that loads messages from firebase into a div.

- Goal is to auto-scroll to the bottom of the div WHEN `relevantMessages` changes, IF the current scroll location is already near
  the bottom.

I tried to do this by adding a watcher to `relevantMessages` that calls a 'scrollToBottom' `method.

Problem is: Error in callback for watcher "relevantMessages":

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined"

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="chat-header">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="messages-area" id="messages-area-id" ref="messagesAreaRef">
      <div
        v-for="(thing, index) in relevantMessages"
        :key="index"
        class="message-row"
      >
        <div class="message">
          <span>{{thing.content}}</span>
          <span>{{thing.timeStamp}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-area">
      ...
  </div>
</template>
```

The JS:

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      relevantMessages: Object,
      partnerObj: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...
  },
  props: {
    ...
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getMessages();
    this.getPartner();
  },
  watch: {
    relevantMessages: function() {
      this.scrollToBottom();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getMessages: function() {
      var that = this;
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/messages/" + that.conversationUID)
        .on("value", function(messages) {
          var result = messages.val();
          that.relevantMessages = result;
        });

      console.log("getting posts");
    },
    sendMessage: function() {
      ...
    },
    scrollToBottom: function() {
      var messagesArea = this.$refs.messagesAreaRef;
      // var messagesArea = document.getElementById("messages-area-id");

      var currentScrollPos = messagesArea.scrollTop;
      // console.log(currentScrollPos);
      var totalDivHeight = messagesArea.scrollHeight;
      if (currentScrollPos <= totalDivHeight - 100) {
        messagesArea.scrollTop(totalDivHeight);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The errors themselves:

> - vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "relevantMessages": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined"
> - TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined

Comment: did it work with `document.getElementById("messages-area-id")` ?

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of this.$refs?

Comment: @Dadboz No, it did not work either. I can change the CSS by referencing the div's ID without issue, so its definitely finding it there, so I dont get why it isn't working

Comment: @cppstudy when I console log the ref AND the getElementById, they both console log correctly

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the component itself is not yet mounted at this time. So all `$refs` are `undefined`. Try out the alternative syntax of watch ([Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)) in `mounted()`. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you are suggesting. Could you rephrase in a beginner friendly way? When I check out that link I'm not sure what to take from it

Comment: Avoid linking to documentation without context, and include any relevant snippets in your answer. See "Provide context for links" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Also, in @9142016's case, the ref appears to be defined when the watcher function is called.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your implementation:

- ```js
  relevantMessages: Object,
  ```

  `Object` does not seem to be a valid initial value for `relevantMessages`. You should set this to either an empty object (`{}`) or an empty array (`[]`).
- ```js
  messagesArea.scrollTop(totalDivHeight);
  ```

  `scrollTop` is not a function, it should be used like `messagesArea.scrollTop = totalDivHeight`.
- Your implementation for scrolling to the bottom is incorrect; `currentScrollPos` will always be less than the height of its container if it's near the *top*. To check if it's near the bottom, you should have `currentScrollPos >= totalDivHeight - messagesArea.clientHeight - 100`

Now, even with the above changes, it appears the watcher will run and execute before Vue has a chance to actually re-render and update the DOM (thus, the scrolling will always be one node behind), so you must call your `scrollToBottom` after the ["next tick"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick):

```js
watch: {
  relevantMessages() {
    this.$nextTick(this.scrollToBottom);
  }
},
```

I created a working example in CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-tqo4k.